# cassert not found when Clang compiles project that uses Boost

Tags: boost, cmake, msys

I have a project that compiles fine under GCC 12.2.0. I would like to compile it under Clang 11.0.0, but cannot.

This project uses the Boost library. (1.81)

When I tried to compile under Clang, I got the following error relatively early on:

```
 In file included from /C/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/qvm/vec.hpp:10:
/C/msys64/mingw64/include/boost/qvm/assert.hpp:10:12: fatal error: 'cassert' file not found
#               include <cassert>
```

What I have tried so far:

- Swapping stdlib between libc++ and libstdc++, neither worked
- Installing the mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-boost under mingw64. I could not figure out how to use Boost_ROOT to point cmake to the correct boost version. (And it turns out this approach was faulty anyways)
- Using the clang64 shell instead of the mingw64 shell, along with the appropriate clang-specific packages

Nothing has worked so far though. It still fails on that cassert include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I needed to know to fix this:

1: MSYS provides a clang64 shell for doing anything clang-related. It must be used for compiling anything with Clang on MSYS2!

2: The mingw64 and clang64 shells share the same package repository. Anything installed one one will appear in the other.

3: Clang was severely outdated (11.0.0) and the newest version (15.0.07) does not have this issue. Pacman -Syyuu did not find this. Wiping all clang packages and reinstalling them fixed it.

4: I was pointing cmake to the wrong clang executable. I was using (-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang.exe) when I should have been using (-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/clang64/bin/clang.exe) [and the clang++ as well]